# How does `optimizer.step()` perform an in-place operation?

Tags: pytorch, gradient

Here is a simple example that results in an in-place operation error.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from collections import OrderedDict
from torch import optim

torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

class Loss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Loss, self).__init__()
    def forward(self, x, target):
        return x[0,0,0,0]

def block(in_channels, features, name):
    return nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                     out_channels=features,
                     kernel_size=3,
                     padding=1,
                     bias=False)
class SharedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shared_layer = block(in_channels=3, features=1, name="wow")

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.shared_layer(x)
        return x


class Network1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = block(in_channels=1, features=1, name="wow-1")
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)
    
class Network2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = block(in_channels=1, features=1, name="wow-2")
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.conv(x))

shared_net = SharedNetwork()
net_1 = Network1()
segmentor = Network2()

optimizer = optim.Adam(list(shared_net.parameters()) + list(segmentor.parameters()), lr=1e-6)
optimizer_conf = optim.Adam(list(shared_net.parameters()), lr=1e-6)
loss_fn = Loss()

# 2. Run a forward pass
fake_data = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255
target_data_1 = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255
target_data_2 = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255


optimizer.zero_grad()
optimizer_conf.zero_grad()

features = shared_net(fake_data)
segmented = segmentor(features)
s_loss = loss_fn(segmented, target_data_2)
s_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
optimizer.step()


out_1 = net_1(features)
loss = loss_fn(out_1, target_data_1)
loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
optimizer_conf.step()
```

Error message:

```
UserWarning: Error detected in ConvolutionBackward0. No forward pass information available. Enable detect anomaly during forward pass for more information. (Triggered internally at C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:97.)
  Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass

one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 3, 3, 3]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

I was able to solve the problem by changing the order of running the `step` function of optimizers.

```py
optimizer_conf.zero_grad()
optimizer.zero_grad()

features = shared_net(fake_data)
segmented = segmentor(features)
s_loss = loss_fn(segmented, target_data_2)
s_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)


out_1 = net_1(features)
loss = loss_fn(out_1, target_data_1)
loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
optimizer_conf.step()
optimizer.step()
```

The following questions, however, remain:

1. How does the `step` method cause an inplace operation in convolution?
2. Why does moving the steps to the end of the file resolve this error?

*NOTE*: The loss function is used for simplicity, using dice-loss also results in the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering the question, I have to mention that it seems having multiple optimizers for one set of parameters is anti-pattern and it's better to be avoided.

1. How does the step method cause an inplace operation in convolution?
   A: step method adds the gradients to the weights, so it does something like the following:

```
param.weight += param.grad
```

which can be interpreted as an in place operation

2. Why does moving the steps to the end of the file resolve this error?
   A: Obviously, by moving the step method after the second backward method, the above-mentioned operation is not executed. As a result, there are no in-place operations and no errors raised due to their existence.

To sum up, it's best to have only one optimizer for one set of parameters, the previous example could coded in the following way:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from collections import OrderedDict
from torch import optim

torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

class Loss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Loss, self).__init__()
    def forward(self, x, target):
        return x[0,0,0,0]
def block(in_channels, features, name):
    return nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                     out_channels=features,
                     kernel_size=(3,3),
                     padding=1,
                     bias=False)
class SharedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shared_layer = block(in_channels=3, features=1, name="wow")

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.shared_layer(x)
        return x


class Network1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = block(in_channels=1, features=1, name="wow-1")
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)
    
class Network2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = block(in_channels=1, features=1, name="wow-2")
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sigmoid(self.conv(x))
    
torch.manual_seed(0)

shared_net = SharedNetwork()
net_1 = Network1()
net_2 = Network2()

shared_optimizer = optim.Adam(list(shared_net.parameters()), lr=1e-6) 
net_1_optimizer = optim.Adam(list(net_1.parameters()), lr=1e-6)
net_2_optimizer = optim.Adam(list(segmentor.parameters()), lr=1e-6)
loss_fn = Loss()

# 2. Run a forward pass
fake_data = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255
target_data_1 = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255
target_data_2 = torch.randint(0,255,(1, 3, 256, 256))/255

net_2_optimizer.zero_grad()
features = shared_net(fake_data)
net_2_out = net_2(features)
s_loss = loss_fn(net_2_out, target_data_2)
s_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
net_2_optimizer.step()

net_1_optimizer.zero_grad()
shared_optimizer.zero_grad()
out_1 = net_1(features)
loss = loss_fn(out_1, target_data_1)
loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
net_1_optimizer.step()
shared_optimizer.step()
```

Note: If you want to have two different learning rates for different losses applied to one set of parameters, you can multiply the losses based on their importance by a value. For example, you can multiply loss_1 by 0.1 and loss_1 by 0.5. Or, you can use backward hooks as mentioned in this comment:
[backward-hook](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/different-optimizers-for-shared-parameters/160015/5?u=pooya_mohammadi_kaza)